# iOS App Crashes When App is Minimized with MonkeyTalk Built In

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, ui-automation, monkeytalk

**I am using Monkey Talk version 2.0.3.a**

I have  integrated **MonkeyTalk** into my iPhone App,Everything is working great as expected both on device and simulator.

But I  have found that the App crashes when it is **minimized** or the home button is pressed (i.e. whenever the App is sent to the **background**).

I have another build of same App without MonkeyTalk , it does not have MonkeyTalk integrated and this crash does not happen on it, so something about having MonkeyTalk incorporated is making it crash.

When I run it through Xcode debugger and logging, I can see that something in MonkeyTalk is faulting when the App is sent to the background (it only shows the assembly code that it faults on).

If anyone has any insight on what is going on or why this may be happening, I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
Stack Trace :

Incident Identifier: CA1FB909-46AC-45AB-9DFE-62F7D7A60B30  
CrashReporter Key:   29e221ff825afca768fe1cba2cf6aea7ac922060  
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2  
Process:             AppName MonkeyTalkcopy [5269]  
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/4430DBD0-10DA-4F61-B20D-9424C6F760AD/AppName MonkeyTalkcopy.app/AppName MonkeyTalkcopy   
Identifier:          se.appName.test  
Version:             1.9.9 (1.9.9)  
Code Type:           ARM (Native)  
Parent Process:      launchd [1]  

Date/Time:           2014-04-29 11:49:13.872 +0530  
OS Version:          iOS 7.1 (11D167)  
Report Version:      104  

Exception Type:  00000020  
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d  
Highlighted Thread:  0  

Application Specific Information:
se.appName.test failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 13.510 (user 13.510, system 0.000), 56% CPU   
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 6.379, 27% CPU  

Thread 0:  
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3a7636f8 _sigtramp + 0  
1   ???                             0x00356a7c 0 + 3500668
2   AppName MonkeyTalkcopy          0x0011b260 -[UIApplication(MTReady)    mtApplicationDidEnterBackground:] (UIApplication+MTReady.m:95)
3   UIKit                           0x3226950c -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 876
4   UIKit                           0x321eb22e -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 886
5   UIKit                           0x321eadf4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
6   AppName MonkeyTalkcopy          0x0011b3b8 -[UIApplication(MTReady) mtSendEvent:] (UIApplication+MTReady.m:108)
7   UIKit                           0x3224f400 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 612
8   GraphicsServices                0x34858b52 _PurpleEventCallback + 606
9   GraphicsServices                0x3485873a PurpleEventCallback + 30
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2f98183c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2f9817d6 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2f97ffa2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1402
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2f8ea7a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2f8ea586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15  GraphicsServices                0x348576ce GSEventRunModal + 134
16  UIKit                           0x3224988c UIApplicationMain + 1132
17  AppName MonkeyTalkcopy          0x0000dd5a main (main.m:16)
18  AppName MonkeyTalkcopy          0x0000d164 start + 36

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a6ed804 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a63c050 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a6362de _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a6eda50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a6ed848 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f98161c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2f97fd3c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f8ea7a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f8ea586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x37c1bee0 RunWebThread(void*) + 416
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a767956 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a7678c6 _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a765ae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a700c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a765c1e _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a765ad8 start_wqthread + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue resolved** by upgrading to latest version of **MonkeyTalk v2.0.4**

https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/whats-new

```
Bug Fixes

iOS agent:
    Crash when application is sent into background
```

**App crash on Minimizing or pressing Home button(App sent to background ) is solved in new MonkeyTalk version V2.0.4.**

> **But now there is one more issue App crashes in touch event when recording or executing in device/Simulator**
>
> In iphone device/simulator  when I try to record an action in my app with a touch event it crashes. Also when I try to use a recorded script while executing touch event it make the app to crash. Below is my crash report.

```
Incident Identifier: 5F4C1528-D282-41BE-95B4-15F059CC37BE
CrashReporter Key:   29e221ff825afca768fe1cba2cf6aea7ac922060
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             App copy [5567]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/E7177F26-8A2C-4B1D-87FD-3D99A4A7D1DD/APP copy.app/APP copy
Identifier:          se.AppName.timereport
Version:             2.0.0 (2.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-04-29 17:26:12.393 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 7.1 (11D167)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information: se.AppName.timereport failed to exit in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 7.690 (user 7.690, system 0.000), 61% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 3.366, 27% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3a7636f8 _sigtramp + 0
1   APP copy                0x0022ffd2 -[UIView(MTReady) propertyName:parent:]  (UIView+MTReady.m:643)
2   APP copy                0x00230144 -[UIView(MTReady) iVarName] (UIView+MTReady.m:660)
3   APP copy                0x0022f822 -[UIView(MTReady) rawMonkeyIDCandidates] (UIView+MTReady.m:578)
4   APP copy                0x00230ac2 -[UIView(MTReady) baseMonkeyID] (UIView+MTReady.m:755)
5   APP copy                0x0022fb3c -[UIView(MTReady) monkeyID] (UIView+MTReady.m:609)
6   APP copy                0x0022bf24 -[UIView(MTReady) handleMonkeyTouchEvent:withEvent:] (UIView+MTReady.m:220)
7   APP copy                0x0021a608 -[MonkeyTalk handleEvent:] (MonkeyTalk.m:609)
8   APP copy                0x0022965e -[UIApplication(MTReady) mtSendEvent:] (UIApplication+MTReady.m:100)
9   UIKit                           0x321e953c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7116
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2f981fe4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2f9814aa __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2f97fc9a __CFRunLoopRun + 626
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2f8ea7a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2f8ea586 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15  GraphicsServices                0x348576ce GSEventRunModal + 134
16  UIKit                           0x3224988c UIApplicationMain + 1132
17  APP copy                0x0004dc64 main (main.m:16)
18  App copy                0x0004c87c start + 36
```

> Any help to fix this will much appericiated